# Include .gitlab-ci.yml multiple times with different configuration each time

Tags: gitlab-ci

We have a GitLab CI/CD `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file that builds software packages. This `.gitlab-ci.yaml` has a variable that determines which operating system release the package should be built for. We would like to use the `include` keyword in other GitLab projects to include this `.gitlab-ci.yaml` to allow us to build packages. We want to build this package for multiple operating system releases. However, we cannot as GitLab does not allow us to `include` the same file twice. Is there another way to do this?

To see this more concretely, assume the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file we want to include in other projects is this:

```
# common/gitlab-templates/.gitlab-ci.yaml
variables:
  OS_RELEASE: 10.0

build-package:
  script: echo "building for $OS_RELEASE"
```

In another GitLab project we would like to do something like this:

```
# Build for version 8.0
include:
  - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
    file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'
    variables:
      OS_RELEASE: 8.0

# Build for version 9.0
include:
  - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
    file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'
    variables:
      OS_RELEASE: 9.0

# Build for version 10.0
include:
  - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
    file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'
    variables:
      OS_RELEASE: 10.0
```

However, the above is not valid `.gitlab-ci.yaml` syntax.

How do we get around this?

Comment: Note that if this did work you would get three jobs all named build-package:
These jobs would overwrite each other and not do what is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use extends ?

```
    # common/gitlab-templates/.gitlab-ci.yaml
    variables:
      OS_RELEASE: change_me

    .build-package:
      script: echo "building for $OS_RELEASE"
```

In another GitLab project we would like to do something like this:

```
    # Build for version 8.0
    include:
      - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
        file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'

    build-package:
      extends: .build-package
      variables:
        OS_RELEASE: 8.0

    # Build for version 9.0
    include:
      - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
        file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'

    build-package:
      extends: .build-package
      variables:
        OS_RELEASE: 9.0

    # Build for version 10.0
    include:
      - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
        file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'

    build-package:
      extends: .build-package
      variables:
        OS_RELEASE: 10.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Robert-Jan's answer comes close, but this will work for your primary `.gitlab-ci.yml` (tested and verified) and do what you are attempting:

```
include:
  - project: 'common/gitlab-templates'
    file:    '.gitlab-ci.yml'

# Build for version 8.0
build-package1:
  extends: .build-package
  variables:
    OS_RELEASE: "8.0"

# Build for version 9.0    
build-package2:
  extends: .build-package
  variables:
    OS_RELEASE: "9.0"

# Build for version 10.0
build-package3:
  extends: .build-package
  variables:
    OS_RELEASE: "10.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I Assume you want to use different variables depending on the environment.

You can use a `.gitlab-ci-vars.yml` file and define multiple vars sections and load a different vars section based on your environment. Consider the following `.gitlab-ci-vars.yml`:

```
variables:
  FORCE_COLOR: 1

.vars-dev:
  variables:
    OS_RELEASE: 9.0
    
.vars-prod:
  variables:
    OS_RELEASE: 10.0
```

And now use it in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
include:
  - ".gitlab-ci-vars.yml"

...

publish:dev:
  variables: !reference [.vars-dev, variables]
  resource_group: dev
  environment:
    name: dev
  only:
    - develop

publish:prod:
  variables: !reference [.vars-prod, variables]
  resource_group: prod
  environment:
    name: prod
  only:
    - master
```

This will merge the environment variables of the global scope with the environments of the targeted scope.

Comment: I want the "code" in the `include`'ed YAML file to be run once for each operating system release. Your example does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the same file multiple times, with different inputs. However, if multiple jobs with the same name are added to one pipeline, each additional job overwrites the previous job with the same name. You must ensure the configuration prevents duplicate job names.

For example, including the same configuration multiple times with different inputs:

```
include:
  - local: path/to/my-super-linter.yml
    inputs:
      type: docs
      lint-path: "doc/"
  - local: path/to/my-super-linter.yml
    inputs:
      type: yaml
      lint-path: "data/yaml/"
```

The configuration in `path/to/my-super-linter.yml` ensures the job has a unique name each time it is included:

```
spec:
  inputs:
    type:
    lint-path:
---
"run-$[[ inputs.type ]]-lint":
script: ./lint --$[[ inputs.type ]] --path=$[[ inputs.lint-path ]]
```

Check [Define inputs for configuration added with include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/inputs.html#include-the-same-file-multiple-times)